# Random small icons missing in Gnome shell

Tags: icons, gnome-shell

Small icons all throughout Ubuntu's gnome shell usually in the title bar of a window in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS
Some Examples:

[image: AskUbuntu isn't letting me put an image on the questions due to my low number of points, so they have linked it instead]

In the top left(beside 'Home'), top right(beside minimize icon), and bottom left(furthest down icon) one can the default image icon instead of the useful(left arrow, right arrow, etc) icons. This happens in many systems applications including Tweaks, Settings, etc.

I have tried changing themes, the icons do not come back in any theme.

Anyone has any solution to bring back the normal icons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I also landed in same issue. It was solved by simply changing icons to Yaru.
Open Gnome tweak > Apperance > select icons to Yaru or any other icon that works proper.

Comment: Thanks! This seems to be a problem in the Oranchelo Icon Pack then